# How do I see last month's (RDS) cost per instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, aws-billing

For some reason, I am finding it hard to understand where to access this information.

In last month's bill, I see that my RDS has 14000 hours, which is weird since a month only has 730 hours, and I only have 1 RDS.

[image]

So my question, what is the most straight forward way to list the cost per RDS instance of a specific month in AWS?

A step by step guide would be extremely helpful, as AWS billing and cost reports can be a jungle to navigate.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, even if a month has 720 hours. One RDS can have been multiple read replicas if its a cluster. In your case it looks like you have one read replica besides your master. Which would be 2 instances of db.t2.micro i.e. 24 * 30 = 720 hours for instance and 720 *2 = 1440 hours for 2 instances

Comment: Enabling Multi-AZ in RDS also bills 2 hours of usage per wall-clock hour because of the redundant hardware involved.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Cost Explorer.

1. Go to [Cost Management](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-reports/home) console.
2. Select Cost Explorer in the menu.
3. Set filter: Service=Relational Database Service

You can then group by usage type or instance type as necessary.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show per instance (or as detailed as that), but it is a great start! I can see that you can group by allocation cost tags as well, so I think this is the right view - just needs tags!